# Jenkinsfile DSL sourcecode

Tags: intellij-idea, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am developing new pipeline within Jenkinsfile using intelliJ.

When I was using jenkins 1 with pipeline-dsl plugin I could go into the source code and see how DSL was actually implemented in `org.jenkins-ci.plugins:job-dsl-core`. I would like to have the same ability with Jenkinsfile.

Can I somehow connect Jenkinsfile DSL and intellij to have there proper code completion and sourcecode insight?

Comment: You say you want to be able to "look at the source code." I'm assuming you mean the Java source that is used to parse and execute the `Jenkinsfile`? I am fascinated that you were able to link your Jenkins 1 pipeline to the plugin source. My experience has been that you have to actually download it or view it on GitHub. The new pipeline plugin can be found [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) - from that you can see that it's actually a "suite of plugins that lets you orchestrate automation, simple or complex."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to have access to the sourcecode for the Pipeline Plugin suite of plugins when working on ANY Jenkins pipeline script, whether global or otherwise, you will have to include the necessary libraries as dependencies.

I'm working on my current [global pipeline library](https://github.com/terradatum/jenkins-pipeline-library).
[image: Global Pipeline Library as IntelliJ Project and Module]

Here adding the CPS library via "Project Structure" menu item:
[image]

1. Go to Libraries
2. Click the add button and select "From Maven..."
3. Type in the correct GAV (in this case `com.cloudbees:groovy-cps:1.9`)
4. Click the magnifying glass button - IntelliJ will search Maven Central (and whatever other repos you've configured in the Maven IntelliJ configuration or via your `settings.xml`) and download them to an your local cache.

Rinse and repeat until you've got all the dependencies you need.

When you're done, it should look something like this:
[image: Groovy CPS library added to Groovy project]

I found that the minimum useful were:

- `com.cloudbees:groovy-cps:1.9`
- `org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-api:2.+`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [this approach](http://st-g.de/2016/08/jenkins-pipeline-autocompletion-in-intellij) yet?

Comment: Yeah. it helps but I wanted to look into source code too.

Comment: @IgorKonoplyanko, this actually answers part of your question "somehow connect Jenkinsfile DSL and intellij to have there proper code completion and sourcecode insight?"